# function return Promise{ <pending> } in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

if I store the value of the promise return by a function in a variable and then print it then it shows Promise { pending }.
Why ? Because till 3 seconds promise will definitely resolved.

```
let move = false;
function my() {
return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
        if (move === true)
            return resolve("resolved")
        else
            return reject(new Error("Rejected"));
    })
}

let obj = my().then((result) => {
    console.log("result", result);
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log("my error");
});

//it prints promise{ <pending> }
setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("time", obj)},3000
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise should wrap the `setTimeout` function and resolve after 3 seconds is over.

```
let move = false;

function my() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (move) {
        resolve('resolved');
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Rejected'));
      }
    }, 3000);
  });
}

my()
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```